# Hexagon on html with text and some details

Tags: html, css

I want to make a website where is a hexagon, and circle in it, surrounded by some text;
**The hexagon has to be in the middle. In the center there needs to be circle and some lines going to angles**

I have tried many times, its getting weird.

This is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/Farpee/n5Lx0qow/

```
<div class="main-section sec" id="main">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="hexagon"></div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <span>one</span>
            <span>two</span>
            <span>three</span>
            <span>four</span>
            <span>five</span>
            <span>six</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

how to set up css?

[image: This is an image]
Thank you for helping me :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understading is that you are searching for something like this:

```css
.main-section {
  margin-top: 20vh;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 173.21px;
  background-color: #97d5d8;
  margin: 86.60px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 86.60px solid #97d5d8;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 86.60px solid #97d5d8;
}

.outer span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
}

.outer span:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
}

.outer span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}

.outer span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
}

.outer span:nth-of-type(4) {
  bottom: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

.outer span:nth-of-type(5) {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.outer span:nth-of-type(6) {
  bottom: 120px;
  right: 0;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

.line {
  width: 346px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.line:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.line:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.line:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.relative {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="main-section sec" id="main">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="hexagon">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="circle">
      </div>
    </div>
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
    <span>three</span>
    <span>four</span>
    <span>five</span>
    <span>six</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the long term it might be easier to use svg though for this stuff (it will take a little longer to learn but you'll benefit on the long run). Also both examples (my response as well as the code you posted) are using a lot of hardcoded data (so is pretty hard to make it responsive). You should usually try to avoid this.

Also please note I didn't focused on cleaning-up css (or improve it). So you might want to take a look on that as well. I mostly tried to give you a direction on how you can achieve it :)